# Finding the probability of Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given that a cabbage weighs more than 1.5 kg, what is the probability that it weighs between $2$ and $2.5$ kg?

I have the following data:

\begin{align} \\
& \mu = 2.4 && \sigma=0.7 && X\sim N(\mu ,\sigma ^2 ) \\
\end{align}

And I have calculated the following:
\begin{align} \\
& P(X<1.5)&=P(X>-1.5)&=1-P(X\leq -1.5)&=0.9332\\
& P(2\leq X\leq 2.5)&=P(X \leq 2.5)-P(X\leq 2)&=0.9938-0.9772&=0.0166\\
\end{align}

(I hope it's correct)

I have also found a formula for the probability that the weight difference between two random cabbages is more than 1 kg to be:

\begin{align} \\
& 2\left( 1-\phi\left( \frac{1}{(0.7)(\sqrt{2})} \right) \right) \\
\end{align}

How can I use this data to calculate the probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the problem, you are given a condition. Use the definition of conditional probability:
$$ P(2 < X < 2.5 | X > 1.5) = \frac{P(2 < X < 2.5)}{P(X > 1.5)}. $$

Try and find all of these probabilities and you will get your answer. Luckily for normal distribution, these are easy to find. Let me know if this is enough help, or if you need more guidance!

EDIT: I understand your correction, thank you!

Comment: I havew written wrong in the exercise. I have fixed the error now.